# How do I check if a page is bookmarked

Tags: asp.net, bookmarks

Without resorting to using an ActiveX or some other kind of client side coding:

Is it possible to determine if a visitor to a website arrived to a page via his bookmarks or the home page?

Personally I think its impossible, but I would like to be sure or proven wrong.

The way I am doing something like this at the moment is:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

If I don't find anything there, I currently deduce the user had me bookmarked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, no.

Long answer, not in a portable foolproof manner.

Comment: I think the short answer is the answer :)))

Answer (score 5):

Not a foolproof way. But, you can set the bookmark to have a querystring.
e.g. stackoverflow.com/?bmark=y

And on server side, you can check for this.

Comment: It's a good idea but how does the server set the bookmark? This requires co-operation from the user in adding "?bmark=y" when bookmarking the page.

Comment: The url (with ?bmark=y) can be set in a client side javascvcript variable & one can provide a button to "Bookmark this". On clicking of the button, user will be prompted to add the text by which to identify the url (with ?bmark=y)

Comment: I guess that's one solution (see http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/01/add-to-favorites-ie-bookmark-firefox.html) but I'd never use it; I'd prefer the button (or CTRL-D) already built into Firefox et al to one on a page (I almost never press PRINT buttons on the page either, CTRL-P is so much handier).

Comment: So that covers portable, but not foolproof :-). Still, I learn't something today so thanks for that.

Comment: thank you, your answer is great, but again.. client side scripting or some user driven way is required..+1 for cool trick though

Answer (score 3):

Same short answer as Pax.

Long answer... unfortunately, it is possible to some extent in IE. You can use the [saveFavorite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531069(VS.85).aspx) persistence behavior to try to store some data and then see if you get it back later. If you do, your page load was from a bookmark.

You can also detect whether your page is the user's homepage - though this doesn't necessarily mean that they arrived at your page using that method - using the isHomePage method on the [homePage behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531418(VS.85).aspx).

Please don't, though. It's violently horrible. IE's “default behaviors” are an abomination unto the Web.

Answer (score 1):

There is away but it requires a clickstream datawarehouse that also parses your webserver log files at a suffcient rate.

Most that I have seen do ETL on log files in a +24h routine so the best guess is that this vistor used there bookmark last time.  But then if its important to the business that you see if they used a bookmark there may be a case for +Mins ETL

But this is not fool proof either and you get the issues with IP address ranges et al but....

The Fav Icon can be used as this will be a get request on the webserver for an IP which you can also tie up to log on or other tracking mechanism